# VBA Compile error: Expected end of statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to code a combo box in a form such that it automatically filters the options as the user types. I have a code but I keep getting a compile error. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub UTIL_FCLTY_ID_Change()
    If Nz(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text) = “” Then
        Me.Form.Filter = “”
        Me.FilterOn = False
    ElseIf Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Me.Form.Filter = “[UTILITY FACILITY TYPE NAME:] = ‘” & _
                 Replace(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text, “‘”, “””) & “‘”
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Form.Filter = “[UTILITY FACILITY TYPE NAME:] Like ‘*” & _
                 Replace(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text, “‘”, “””) & “*'”
        Me.FilterOn = True

    End If

    Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.SetFocus
    Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.SelStart = Len(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: That code sample has typesetting quotes (`“”`) instead of plain quotes (`""`).  If your real code also includes typesetting quotes, you should change them to plain quotes.

Comment: Which line of the code triggers the compile error?  Is it the line which ends with `& “*'”`?  That looks like a quote problem ... notice how it affects the syntax coloring at that point.

Comment: There are two specific errors now. 1. In the Else if the error is Expected: list separator or ) --> This one highlights the "'" at the end of the statement. 2. In the Else if the error is Expected: expression --> This one highlights the apostrophe in "*'"

Answer (score 1):

As @HansUp mentioned, you use non-standard quotes and non-standard apostrophe. Replace them with correct one.
Second issue is with this statement: ***"""***. VBA compiler sees it as ***"" "*** (empty string and unclosed quote). You need to use double quote inside quote to workaround it: ***"""""***

Finally your procedure should look like:

```
Private Sub UTIL_FCLTY_ID_Change()
    If Nz(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text) = "" Then
        Me.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Exit Sub 'there's nothing to proceed ;)
    End If

    If Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Me.Form.Filter = "[UTILITY FACILITY TYPE NAME:] = '" & _
                 Replace(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text, "'", """") & "'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Form.Filter = "[UTILITY FACILITY TYPE NAME:] Like '*" & _
                 Replace(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text, "'", """") & "*'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If

    Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.SetFocus
    Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.SelStart = Len(Me.UTIL_FCLTY_ID.Text)

End Sub
```